# when should I use an After trigger instead of a Before trigger?

Tags: postgresql

Afaik, although I'm pretty new to Postgres, Before-triggers are less expensive then After-triggers.

After all, if you want to change the current record (using `NEW`), you can change the record before it is written. In contrast, with After-triggers you need two writes: 1 verbatim write and 1 as a result of the after-trigger.

At the same time, all functionality that is available in after-triggers seems to be available in before-triggers. If I'm not mistaken.

So why would you ever use After-triggers to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're changing the record upon which the trigger is acting use a BEFORE trigger.   If you're doing some complex logic that may prevent the record from being changed, use a BEFORE trigger.

Almost anything else, use an AFTER trigger.  An example might be where you're inserting child records which rely upon the primary key of a record being inserted.  For example, if you're adding an entry to a history table for a newly inserted row. The parent row won't exist in the BEFORE trigger, so would fail foreign key checks.